# Double value added when setting background-repeat to repeat-x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little strange problem compared with jQuery('.class').css(...);

```
jQuery('#ns-background-repeat').on('change', function(){
    //alert(jQuery(this).val());
    jQuery(this).css({ 'background-repeat' : jQuery(this).val() });
    jQuery('.test').text(  jQuery(this).css('background-repeat') );
});
```

Please let me know why it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/eXa4y/2/

Chrome: http://gyazo.com/42cd909cc0b1c17023975f034e5a4728.

Firefox: http://gyazo.com/aa74f7e00fd898a7c43c2d7e44d0d17c - works well.

Comment: Please inline your code in the question, don't just link to a jsfiddle.

Comment: And what are you trying to apply background-repeat to? The select? Makes no sense!

Comment: It doesn't have any sense but it's only example. Moreover it works using Firefox but doesn't work using Chrome. Please select i.e. No-repeat and in Chrome when you will check the code there will be style="background-repeat: repeat no-repeat", so two values. In Firefox it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXa4y/8/) may help describe the situation

The result of each browser appears in agreement with the CSS3 spec for [background-repeat](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-repeat)

When setting `$someElement.css({ 'background-repeat' : 'repeat-x' });`

Chrome sets the style attribute to `background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;`

Firefox/IE set the style attribute to `background-repeat: repeat-x;`

(testing in latest versions of each browser Chrome 30, FF 24, IE 10)

The spec specifies

> ‘repeat-x’
>   Computes to ‘repeat no-repeat’.

So the two are technically equivalent, just different implementations.

repeat-x = x: repeat, y: no-repeat